# window.print not printing all pages in IE

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a page that contains iframes, i want to print them all using `window.print()` it works in chrome but not working in IE, it just prints the first page not the rest.[image: this is the exact page that i want to print![][1]]
it just prints out the first page not other 5 pages.
any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: what is the style you applied on element that contain Iframes?

Comment: @ZohaibWaqar i have set <body style="margin:0; overflow:auto">

Comment: this is body style.. you didnot use any container for Iframes.. mean any div  just before iframe?

Comment: @ZohaibWaqar 
<div style="height:auto; overflow-x:hidden;">

<div id="topframe" style="height:41px;"></div>


</div>

Comment: just remove style="height:41px;" and then check the output on IE ...

Comment: @ZohaibWaqar  i did, it gets the entire contents but not prints all of them in IE except the first page\

Answer (score 1):

Not clear with your situation but to help, in IE window.print will always try to print the browser window and not the iframe window you are in unlike chrome and firefox. 
To print corresponding iframe window in IE, do something like this.

window.top.document.getElementById("iframe-id").contentWindow.focus();
window.top.document.getElementById("iframe-id").contentWindow.print();

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you, these scripts are only gets the inside content of the iframe but it does not print all of the contents it just prints out the first page again!

Comment: If it is still unresolved, can you clarify further on what you mean by pages? Are they already loaded in DOM?